# How to get table data from sqlite database in datatable:Getting TimeOut Exception

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, exception, mono

Below is My Code, i m using Mono android for developing android app with database using visual studio 2010. and not using the ANDROID-SPECIFIC DATABASE OPTIONS

```
Conn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + DB);                
            Conn.Open();
            string stringQuery = "SELECT SpeciesTypeName FROM SpeciesTypes";
            var SqliteCmd = new SqliteCommand(stringQuery, Conn);
            SqliteCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                
            SqliteDataAdapter da = new SqliteDataAdapter(SqliteCmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt != null)
                return dt.Rows.Count;
            else
                return 0;
```

by executing the above code i m getting "TimeOut exception" What will be the reason?

Try to sole this and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
Conn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + DB);
```

to this:

```
Conn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + DB + ";");
```

Depending on the exception this can be useful!